# Problems calling AJAX POST from inside a dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a complex page.
In this pare there is one button.
The click of this button fires a Javascript:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:ShowDifferenze('@item.x', '@item.y')" />
```

This Javascript is in a file .js.
This javascript opens a dialog, loads data with a ajax GET call, and adds some links to the dialog.

```
function ShowDifferenze(cod, link) {
    //Funzionante in popup
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "title", "Mostra differenze");
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "width", 1200);
    $("#dialog").dialog("option", "height", 700);
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    $("#dialog").html('<h2>Loading...</h2><div style="margin-top:1em"><img src="/Content/images/ajax-loader-bar.gif" width="220" height="19" /></div>');
    $("#dialog").load('/Gestione/Fonti/Differenze/' + cod, function () {
        $("#dialog").append('<hr />');
        $("#dialog").append('<div><span><a target="_blank" href="/Gestione/Stazioni/FonteWeb/' + cod + '">Modifica fonte web</a></span></div>');
        $("#dialog").append('<div><span><a target="_blank" href="/Gestione/Fonti/AggiornaFonte/' + cod + '">Aggiorna sorgente</a></span></div>');
        $("#dialog").append('<div><span><a href="/Gestione/Fonti/Differenze/' + cod + '">Salva le differenze in un file</a></span></div>');
        $("#dialog").append('<div><span><a href="' + link + '" target="_blank">VISUALIZZA PAGINA NEL BROWSER</a></span></div>');

        $("#dialog").append('<div <a href="#" onclick="Javascript:Prova()">prova</a></div>');

        $("#dialog").append('<script> ' +
                            'function Prova() '+
                            '{ '+
                            '  alert("Prova"); '+
                            '  $("#dialog").hide(); '+
                            '} '+
                            '</script>');
    });    

    return false;
}
```

The last link calls a javascript.
In the example posted, the javascript works, the alert appears.
The dialog doesn't close correctly, but this isn't the REAL problem.

Instead of an alert, i need to call an AJAX POST, and here is the real problem: if I change the javascript like this:

```
$("#dialog").append('<script> '+
                            'function Prova() '+
                            '{'+
                            '  alert("Prova"); '+
                            '  $.ajax( { '+
                            '            type:"POST", '+
                            '            url : "/Gestione/Fonti/Prova/", ' +   
                            '            data: "id="+cod+"&ApriLink=true", '+
                            '            success: function(data) { alert("Aggiornato!"); }, '+
                            '            error: function (error) { alert("error")); } '+
                            '          });'+
                            '}'+
                            '</script>');
```

nothing works: I don't see the alerts, and the controller is not called.

Any suggestion?

I corrected the code of the javascript as I think it should be ... but still don't work: 
with FIXED "data" works, 
data: "id=abcdefgh&ApriLink=true"
with VARIABLE "data", nothing works
data: "id="+**cod**+"&ApriLink=true"

Comment: First Error found by a friend: i forgot the URL ...
url : "/Gestione/Fonti/Prova/", ' +

Comment: Now the problem changes: with FIXED data, works, but when i try to use variable (correct!) data, nothing works: i still can't see the first alert

Answer (score 0):

Solved: this is the correct "internal" javascript:

```
$("#dialog").append('<script> '+
                            'function AggiornaFonte() ' +
                            '{'+                          
                            '  $.ajax( { ' +
                            '            type: "POST", ' +
                            '            url : "/Gestione/Fonti/Prova/", ' +                           
                            '            data : { id: "'+cod+'", ApriLink: true }, ' +
                            '            success : function(data) { $("#dialog").dialog("close"); }, '+
                            '            error : function (error) { alert("error " + eval(error)); } '+
                            '          });'+
                            '}'+
                            '</script>');
```

Note the 
    data : { id: "'+cod+'", ApriLink: true }
row: the "cod" parameter must be quoted.